# Facebook APP API selection is only limited to version 3.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So I was following an instruction on generating an app token that my app can use to fetch some FB page information.

Here are the step:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools
2. Select Graph API Explorer
3. Log in with your facebook account
4. Get App token for the your application
5. **Select access token for v2.9**
6. Select the permissions what needs to be accessed
7. Create the Token
8. Use it in the API portal settings

I'm stuck on #5 as on the dropdown, 3.0 is the only available option.
[image: here]

I need the **2.9** version as this is to support an existing production API. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: there is no way to downgrade a new app, but you need to tell us what exactly the problem is. what does not work for you with v3,.0?

Comment: In our production, we have an existing Facebook Endpoint config with a value of `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/` and I cannot really change this. I'm hoping to just be able to select the `2.9` version. I'm afraid that the API versions are not backwards compatible

Comment: so what is that existing endpoint exactly? again, you cannot select v2.9 with a new app, only with an old one. and you need to check out the 90 days deprecations or the immediate deprecations. sometimes even using an older version does not work.

Comment: @luschn thanks! This endpoint is an existing production config which uses `v2.9` graph API. The older FB app that our company uses will be deactivated soon. This means we have to create a new FB app and have to notify our API manager to change this setting to v.3. This will be a fun update! :)

Comment: and what endpoint is that exactly? and why will your older app be deactivated soon?